# Converting C headers to Delphi - Opaque Data Type

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

During the conversion process I come across the following C code:

```
/** Opaque data type for the error object.
*/
typedef struct kError * KErrorRef;
```

Where is `kError` declared?

The [conversion tool](http://rvelthuis.de/programs/convertpack.html) provided by Rudy Velthuis produces this code:

```
type
  {$EXTERNALSYM KErrorRef}
  KErrorRef = ^kError;
```

When I try to compile it, I get this error message:

```
[dcc32 Error] ukError.pas(50): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'kError'
```

What is the appropriate way of converting the C code?

Comment: I would declare it as `kError = type Pointer;`

Comment: @Victoria You might hope that would do the job but it's assignment compatible with Pointer

Comment: This is one of the pitfalls. The type does not exist. For C, that is no problem, it only has to know that a KErrorRef is a pointer. So declare it as a Pointer in Delphi. (*My conversion tool does not know if such a type is defined anywhere, so it simply translates this as-is*).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I realized that it one of those, just did not know how to handle it. Thanks for the tools, it saved me lot of typing and looking up type conversions.

Comment: As I wrote, I do all my conversions manually, but with the help of the expert. Saves a lot of time indeed, but needs some manual intervention. It is not like those header conversion tools that try to do everything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Where is kError declared?

Nowhere, because it is not actually needed.

In this declaration:

```c
typedef struct kError * KErrorRef;
```

`struct kError` is an incomplete type, which is allowed when used with a pointer.

The declaration is *roughly* equivalent to this:

```c
// forward declaration of some as-yet unknown struct type
struct kError;

// this is OK; compiler knows the size of a pointer, which is not
// affected by the size of the actual struct being pointed to
typedef kError *KErrorRef;
```

> The conversion tool provided by Rudy Velthuis produces this code

The tool is not producing the correct Delphi code in this instance.  When dealing with a typedef for an incomplete (forward-declared) struct type, it *should* produce Delphi code more like this instead, if the actual struct type is not declared later on:

```pascal
type
  {$EXTERNALSYM KErrorRef}
  KErrorRef = ^kError;
  {$NODEFINE kError}
  kError = record
  end;
```

Comment: FWIW, the docs to my [Conversion Pack](http://rvelthuis.de/programs/convertpack.html) say: "They will not cope with every construct, but with most of them, which leaves only a few items to be converted manually." This was one of those items to be converted manually.

Answer (score 6):

I'd declare an empty record and then a pointer to it. That gives you type safety.

```
type
  KErrorRef = ^kError;
  kError = record
  end;
```

Comment: Empty records are cool anyway. They are, to my knowledge, the only type that can have a size of 0. I sometimes use them as "labels" to indicate the start of a variable size array at the end of a record. Much nicer than an `array[0..0] of Something`.